# What's the difference between an initial value problem and finding the particular solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What exactly does "find the particular solution" mean? Is it exactly the same as saying "solve the initial value problem"? Is it more general because either a boundary value problem and an initial value problem could be particular solutions?

Comment: There are many particular solutions. When looking for the general solutions of a linear differential equation, I always say "find a particular solution"

Comment: @Mattos: Your comment is already a full answer. Please copy down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general solution to a non-homogeneous linear differential equation is a sum of the homogeneous solution and the particular solution, i.e. $y = y_h + y_p$. So saying "solve the initial value problem" means solve your equation in it's entirety, an equation that is made up of a homogeneous solution and particular solution.